# How to use if else in where condition in jpql

Tags: java, spring, database, annotations, jpql

I have a table with 3 column A, B, C. Now I want filter table with a param. If param is null then show all, if param = A then filter table by A, if param = B then filter table by B and so on. How could I can do that in JPQL with @Query annotation ?

Comment: _filter table by A_ did you want to filter by some value in column A ?

Comment: @Eklavya : I mean filter all the values with column A is not null